# Object required with Access Combobox in With statement

Tags: ms-access, vba

this is a separate issue with a previous one that I had submitted and got some help with.

I'm trying to work with some code that checks a numeric ID field on a form (Record set originates from a query of complex joins) and compares it to a combobox of values, that is unbound to the form but originates from a query and fills in the combo box, based on the numeric ID on the form.
The query for the combo box has two columns bound "Name" and "ID" with the ID field hidden.

I keep getting "Object Required" error when attempting to run the code and I've tried everything to debug it. The strange thing is: While debugging, each line of the code returns/contains the values it should, so Access is seeing the combobox as a valid object, but it continues to return the error.

First shot at the code:

```
Dim ParID
Dim i as Integer
ParID = Me.ParentID.Value

With Combo217
   For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
      If .Column(1, i).Value = ParID Then
         .Value = .ItemData(i)
         Exit For
      End If
   Next
End With
```

This didn't work

So I tried putting the combobox into a variable and declaring it specifically as a combobox:

```
Private Sub Command223_Click()
Dim ParID
Dim Combo As ComboBox
Set Combo = Combo217
ParID = Me.ParentID.Value

With Combo
   For i = 0 To Combo.ListCount - 1
      If .Column(1, i).Value = ParID Then
         .Value = .ItemData(i)
         Exit For
      End If
   Next
End With


End Sub
```

Again same error

Finally I tried to explicitly declare the combobox on the form that it's originating from:

```
Private Sub Command223_Click()
Dim ParID
Dim Combo As ComboBox
Set Combo = Forms!DT2!Combo217
ParID = Me.ParentID.Value

With Combo
   For i = 0 To Combo.ListCount - 1
      If .Column(1, i).Value = ParID Then
         .Value = .ItemData(i)
         Exit For
      End If
   Next
End With


End Sub
```

Any and all watch windows and debug prints keep telling me that the loop sees values in the combo box and is even assigning the correct selection in this line:

```
.Value = .ItemData(i)
```

But continues to error out

Oh and the line it's complaining about is:

```
If .Column(1, i).Value = ParID Then
```

Comment: When stepping through it, have you checked all of the values for each item in the line? Eg; Does `i` hold the correct row number? Is the `.Value` value correct? The same for `ParID`?

Comment: It won't step though and continues to hang up on the error line, however `i` does hold the correct row number and `.Value' does contain the correct value and `ParID` indeed contains the correct numeric ID that was assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'll be damned! I found out the problem.

I don't know if it was a syntax issue or logic issue but I removed the `.value` from:

```
If .Column(1, i).Value = ParID Then
```

So here's the new, fully working code:

```
Private Sub Command223_Click()
Dim ParID As Long
Dim Combo As ComboBox
Set Combo = Forms![Deal Tracker Query2]!Combo217
ParID = Me.ParentID.Value

With Combo
   For i = 0 To Combo.ListCount - 1
      If .Column(1, i) = ParID Then
         .Value = .ItemData(i)
         Exit For
      End If
   Next
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah well, [ComboBox.Column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192660.aspx) doesn't return an object, but a Variant. So `.Value` is indeed wrong.